# on bilinear form on free abelian group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, algebraic-surfaces

Let $P$ be a free abelian group of rank $n-2$ with an integral symmetric bilinear form $\left<,\right>$. A sequence of elements $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ in $P$ is called an abstract toric system iff it satisfies the following conditions:

1) $\left<A_i,A_{i+1}\right>=1$ for $i\in[n]$

2) $\left<A_i,A_j\right>=0$ for $i\neq j$  and  $\{i,j\}\neq\{k,k+1\}$ and for all $k\in[n]$

3) $\sum_{i=1}^n\left<A_i,A_i\right>=12-3n$

where $[n]$ means that the cyclic interval which means that we assume that the elements of $[n]$ are in cyclic order in the sense that we consider $[n]$ as a sysytem of representatives of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, I assume that $\left<A_i,A_i\right>\geq -2$ for each $i$. The question is for fixed $n$, say $n=6$, **what is the classifications of sequences of $(A_1^2,A_2^2,\ldots,A_6^2)$, where $A_i^2$ is short for $\left<A_i,A_i\right>$ ?**

This is actually what L.Hille and M.Perling called abstract toric system, they can associate a toric surface to this system and obtain the all the classification of sequence $(A_1^2,\ldots,A_n^2)$ by classification of the corresponding toric surface. The question what I am asking is that 
**Is there a purely combinatoric method to solve this problem without doing geometry as they did?**